Как вывести в консоль текст с кнопок?
Кнопки нажимаются, но когда они нажимаются в консоль должен выводится текст, который на этих кнопках, строки 148-197.
main.py:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Calculator(object):
    def setupUi(self, Calculator):
        Calculator.setObjectName("Calculator")
        Calculator.setFixedSize(257, 386)
        Calculator.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Calculator)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Result = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Result.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-3, 0, 257, 61))
        self.Result.setStyleSheet("font: 25pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.Result.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.Result.setObjectName("Result")
        self.btn_del = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_del.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 65, 65, 65))
        self.btn_del.setStyleSheet("font: 18pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_del.setObjectName("btn_del")
        self.btn_dot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_dot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 65, 65, 65))
        self.btn_dot.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_dot.setObjectName("btn_dot")
        self.btn_proc = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_proc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(128, 65, 65, 65))
        self.btn_proc.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_proc.setObjectName("btn_proc")
        self.btn_div = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_div.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 65, 65, 65))
        self.btn_div.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_div.setObjectName("btn_div")
        self.btn_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 129, 65, 65))
        self.btn_7.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_7.setObjectName("btn_7")
        self.btn_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 129, 65, 65))
        self.btn_8.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_8.setObjectName("btn_8")
        self.btn_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(128, 129, 65, 65))
        self.btn_9.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_9.setObjectName("btn_9")
        self.btn_mult = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_mult.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 129, 65, 65))
        self.btn_mult.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_mult.setObjectName("btn_mult")
        self.btn_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 193, 65, 65))
        self.btn_4.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_4.setObjectName("btn_4")
        self.btn_plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_plus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 257, 65, 65))
        self.btn_plus.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_plus.setObjectName("btn_plus")
        self.btn_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 193, 65, 65))
        self.btn_5.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_5.setObjectName("btn_5")
        self.btn_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(128, 193, 65, 65))
        self.btn_6.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_6.setObjectName("btn_6")
        self.btn_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 257, 65, 65))
        self.btn_1.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"gridline-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_1.setObjectName("btn_1")
        self.btn_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(128, 257, 65, 65))
        self.btn_3.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_3.setObjectName("btn_3")
        self.btn_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 257, 65, 65))
        self.btn_2.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_2.setObjectName("btn_2")
        self.btn_min = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_min.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 193, 65, 65))
        self.btn_min.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_min.setObjectName("btn_min")
        self.btn_zero = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_zero.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 321, 65, 65))
        self.btn_zero.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_zero.setObjectName("btn_zero")
        self.btn_eq = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_eq.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 321, 65, 65))
        self.btn_eq.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 109, 25);")
        self.btn_eq.setObjectName("btn_eq")
        self.btn_eq.raise_()
        self.Result.raise_()
        self.btn_del.raise_()
        self.btn_dot.raise_()
        self.btn_proc.raise_()
        self.btn_div.raise_()
        self.btn_7.raise_()
        self.btn_8.raise_()
        self.btn_9.raise_()
        self.btn_mult.raise_()
        self.btn_4.raise_()
        self.btn_plus.raise_()
        self.btn_5.raise_()
        self.btn_6.raise_()
        self.btn_1.raise_()
        self.btn_3.raise_()
        self.btn_2.raise_()
        self.btn_min.raise_()
        self.btn_zero.raise_()
        Calculator.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Calculator)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Calculator)

    def retranslateUi(self, Calculator):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Calculator.setWindowTitle(_translate("Calculator", "Calculator"))
        self.Result.setText(_translate("Calculator", "0"))
        self.btn_del.setText(_translate("Calculator", "DEL"))
        self.btn_dot.setText(_translate("Calculator", "."))
        self.btn_proc.setText(_translate("Calculator", "%"))
        self.btn_div.setText(_translate("Calculator", "/"))
        self.btn_7.setText(_translate("Calculator", "7"))
        self.btn_8.setText(_translate("Calculator", "8"))
        self.btn_9.setText(_translate("Calculator", "9"))
        self.btn_mult.setText(_translate("Calculator", "x"))
        self.btn_4.setText(_translate("Calculator", "4"))
        self.btn_plus.setText(_translate("Calculator", "+"))
        self.btn_5.setText(_translate("Calculator", "5"))
        self.btn_6.setText(_translate("Calculator", "6"))
        self.btn_1.setText(_translate("Calculator", "1"))
        self.btn_3.setText(_translate("Calculator", "3"))
        self.btn_2.setText(_translate("Calculator", "2"))
        self.btn_min.setText(_translate("Calculator", "-"))
        self.btn_zero.setText(_translate("Calculator", "0"))
        self.btn_eq.setText(_translate("Calculator", "="))

    def functional(self):
        self.btn_zero.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_zero.text()))
        self.btn_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_1.text()))
        self.btn_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_2.text()))
        self.btn_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_3.text()))
        self.btn_4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_4.text()))
        self.btn_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_5.text()))
        self.btn_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_6.text()))
        self.btn_7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_7.text()))
        self.btn_8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_8.text()))
        self.btn_9.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_9.text()))
        self.btn_plus.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_plus.text()))
        self.btn_min.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_min.text()))
        self.btn_mult.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_mult.text()))
        self.btn_div.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_div.text()))
        self.btn_proc.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_proc.text()))

    def write_number(self, number):
        if self.Result.text() == 0:
            self.Result.setText(number)
        else:
            self.Result.setText(self.Result.text() + number)

        print(number)

    def results(self):
        r = eval(self.Result.text())
        self.Result.setText(f"Результат: {str(r)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Calculator = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Calculator()
    ui.setupUi(Calculator)
    Calculator.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



Вы опубликовали код, который демонстрирует проблему - это хорошо и правильно.
Вы плохо рассказали, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается. 
Вы неправильно думаете, что кто-то будет высчитывать строки 148-197 и
смотреть на них. Вы должны либо опубликовать полный текст ошибки,
которую вы получаете или описать ваши действия, которые не приводят к
получению ожидаемого результата. 
Например, при нажатии на кнопку 7,
ожидаю вывод в консоли цифры 7, но почему-то этого не происходит?
Не происходит это потому что вы заключили привязку сигналов
нажати некоторых кнопок к слотам в метод functional(), но нигде его
не вызвали. 
Если вы удалите def functional(self): или  сделаете
вызов self.functional(), то у вас как-то начнет работать ваш калькулятор.



НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета,
и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Некоторые рекмендации и исправление некоторых ошибок
прокомментированы по тексту кода.

Вам еще надо серьезно поработать, чтобы калькулятор заработал правильно.
Удачи вам.



from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Calculator(object):
    def setupUi(self, Calculator):
        Calculator.setObjectName("Calculator")
        Calculator.setFixedSize(257, 386)
        Calculator.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Calculator)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Result = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Result.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-3, 0, 257, 61))
        self.Result.setStyleSheet("font: 25pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.Result.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.Result.setObjectName("Result")
        self.btn_del = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_del.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 65, 65, 65))
        self.btn_del.setStyleSheet("font: 18pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_del.setObjectName("btn_del")
        self.btn_dot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_dot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 65, 65, 65))
        self.btn_dot.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_dot.setObjectName("btn_dot")
        self.btn_proc = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_proc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(128, 65, 65, 65))
        self.btn_proc.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_proc.setObjectName("btn_proc")
        self.btn_div = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_div.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 65, 65, 65))
        self.btn_div.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_div.setObjectName("btn_div")
        self.btn_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 129, 65, 65))
        self.btn_7.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_7.setObjectName("btn_7")
        self.btn_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 129, 65, 65))
        self.btn_8.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_8.setObjectName("btn_8")
        self.btn_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(128, 129, 65, 65))
        self.btn_9.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_9.setObjectName("btn_9")
        self.btn_mult = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_mult.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 129, 65, 65))
        self.btn_mult.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_mult.setObjectName("btn_mult")
        self.btn_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 193, 65, 65))
        self.btn_4.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_4.setObjectName("btn_4")
        self.btn_plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_plus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 257, 65, 65))
        self.btn_plus.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_plus.setObjectName("btn_plus")
        self.btn_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 193, 65, 65))
        self.btn_5.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_5.setObjectName("btn_5")
        self.btn_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(128, 193, 65, 65))
        self.btn_6.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_6.setObjectName("btn_6")
        self.btn_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 257, 65, 65))
        self.btn_1.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"gridline-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn_1.setObjectName("btn_1")
        self.btn_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(128, 257, 65, 65))
        self.btn_3.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_3.setObjectName("btn_3")
        self.btn_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 257, 65, 65))
        self.btn_2.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_2.setObjectName("btn_2")
        self.btn_min = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_min.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 193, 65, 65))
        self.btn_min.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 109, 25);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_min.setObjectName("btn_min")
        self.btn_zero = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_zero.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(64, 321, 65, 65))
        self.btn_zero.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_zero.setObjectName("btn_zero")
        self.btn_eq = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_eq.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 321, 65, 65))
        self.btn_eq.setStyleSheet("font: 22pt \"Nirmala UI\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 109, 25);")
        self.btn_eq.setObjectName("btn_eq")
        self.btn_eq.raise_()
        self.Result.raise_()
        self.btn_del.raise_()
        self.btn_dot.raise_()
        self.btn_proc.raise_()
        self.btn_div.raise_()
        self.btn_7.raise_()
        self.btn_8.raise_()
        self.btn_9.raise_()
        self.btn_mult.raise_()
        self.btn_4.raise_()
        self.btn_plus.raise_()
        self.btn_5.raise_()
        self.btn_6.raise_()
        self.btn_1.raise_()
        self.btn_3.raise_()
        self.btn_2.raise_()
        self.btn_min.raise_()
        self.btn_zero.raise_()
        Calculator.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Calculator)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Calculator)

    def retranslateUi(self, Calculator):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Calculator.setWindowTitle(_translate("Calculator", "Calculator"))
        self.Result.setText(_translate("Calculator", "0"))
        self.btn_del.setText(_translate("Calculator", "DEL"))
        self.btn_dot.setText(_translate("Calculator", "."))
        self.btn_proc.setText(_translate("Calculator", "%"))
        self.btn_div.setText(_translate("Calculator", "/"))
        self.btn_7.setText(_translate("Calculator", "7"))
        self.btn_8.setText(_translate("Calculator", "8"))
        self.btn_9.setText(_translate("Calculator", "9"))
        self.btn_mult.setText(_translate("Calculator", "x"))
        self.btn_4.setText(_translate("Calculator", "4"))
        self.btn_plus.setText(_translate("Calculator", "+"))
        self.btn_5.setText(_translate("Calculator", "5"))
        self.btn_6.setText(_translate("Calculator", "6"))
        self.btn_1.setText(_translate("Calculator", "1"))
        self.btn_3.setText(_translate("Calculator", "3"))
        self.btn_2.setText(_translate("Calculator", "2"))
        self.btn_min.setText(_translate("Calculator", "-"))
        self.btn_zero.setText(_translate("Calculator", "0"))
        self.btn_eq.setText(_translate("Calculator", "="))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Calculator):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

#        self.btn_zero.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_zero.text()))
# Будьте проще -----------------------------------------------> vvv <-----------
        self.btn_zero.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number("0"))
        
        self.btn_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number("1"))
        self.btn_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number("2"))
# и так далее ...        
        self.btn_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_3.text()))
        self.btn_4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_4.text()))
        self.btn_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_5.text()))
        self.btn_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_6.text()))
        self.btn_7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_7.text()))
        self.btn_8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_8.text()))
        self.btn_9.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_9.text()))
        self.btn_plus.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_plus.text()))
        self.btn_min.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_min.text()))
        
#        self.btn_mult.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_mult.text()))
# !!! ---------------------------------------------------------> v <---- !!!
        self.btn_mult.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number('*'))
        
        self.btn_div.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_div.text()))
        self.btn_proc.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_proc.text()))
# +++
        self.btn_eq.clicked.connect(self.results)                      # +++

    def write_number(self, number):
#       if self.Result.text() ==  0 :
# !!! -------------------------> v^v <---------------------------------- !!!
        if self.Result.text() == '0':
            self.Result.setText(number)
        else:
            self.Result.setText(self.Result.text() + number)

        print(number)

    def results(self):
        r = eval(self.Result.text())
        self.Result.setText(f"Результат: {str(r)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()                                              # !!! +++
    w.show()                                                      # !!! +++
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



